# How to create Single Page Application (SPA) in java with hibernate and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, single-page-application

I'm trying to choose best set of tools to create Single Page Applications. I would like to be able to use Java and Hibernate on server side along with MySQL. But what about ajax layer of SPA? 
Maybe I have entirely wrong idea about that and Java and Hibernate make no sense in this case? But than how to implement complex server side operations?

Comment: There are several ways to skin this cat, what technologies are you familiar with currently? I would look at some of the robust .js frameworks to handle data binding, routing, templating, etc.. You can do it yourself in straight .js/jQuery but I happen to like Angular.js, knockout.js, and ember.js more. There are lots of Java web frameworks, some even specifically designed for RESTful interfaces. I am partial to using good old Spring but thats me.

Comment: I am confused. I thought that Hibernate and ajax are JavaScript things. If you mean JavaScript then the Java tag is incorrect.

Comment: @mconlin, those are all JavaScript and ŁukaszM said Java. If you **knew** that ŁukaszM meant Java**Script** then it would have helped to have the tag changed, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use angularJS for creating Single Page Application. this is the best framework i found for SPA development so far and using in most of projects developing which needs SPA.

for sample application refer to [github](https://github.com/xvitcoder/spring-mvc-angularjs)

and detail about [angularJS](http://angularjs.org/)

Comment: angularJS is JavaScript, right? ŁukaszM said **Java** and the tag did too. If you **knew** that ŁukaszM meant Java**Script** then it seems strange to me that no one said anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's rather question of UI part. The page asks a server for pages data. Java + hibernate could be used to implement service (e.g. REST service which returns data in JSON format). You can use SpringMVC to implement the service.

AJAX calls the service and process obtained data.